# Problems with ob_file_callback and fwrite

Tags: php, header, case, fwrite

```
<?php

$forks = 2;

switch ($forks) {
    case 1:
        $ob_file = fopen('case1.txt','w');
        function ob_file_callback($buffer)
{
        global $ob_file;
        fwrite($ob_file,$buffer);
}
        ob_start('ob_file_callback');
        echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        ob_end_flush();

        header("LOCATION: case1.php");

    case 2:
    $ob_file = fopen('case2.txt','w');
function ob_file_callback($buffer)
{
  global $ob_file;
  fwrite($ob_file,$buffer);
}
ob_start('ob_file_callback');
echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
ob_end_flush();
    ;
     header("LOCATION: case2.php");
        }


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

If I choose $forks = 1, it write to case2.txt which is nuts but it does. Not only does it fail to redirect LOCATION, but it won't even show the default page. It claims there's an issue on the header location because headers have already been sent, which is surreal. Then, even though I'm not asking it to redeclare ob_file_callback because it's in case 2 and I've opted for case 1, it claims cannot redeclare ob_file_callback on the ob_file_callback that's sitting inside case 2.

If I choose $forks = 2, it doesn't write into any file whatsoever and just claims it can't modify header information so it's another header relocation fail, which is also stupid. It does however give me the default page, but that just confuses me further.

My problem with fwrite, ob_start or ob_end_flush or whatever's doing the writing to file, is that it'll only write it once. Either that or it's erasing the file everytime it opens it, so the resulting issue is that when forks 1 does indeed write to case2.txt, it's always only ever 1 string sitting there.

---

First round of corrections:

```
    <?php

     function ob_file_callback($buffer)
{
     global $ob_file;
     fwrite($ob_file,$buffer);
}
$forks = 1;
switch ($forks) {
    case 1:
     $ob_file = fopen('case1.txt','w');

     ob_start('ob_file_callback');
     echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     ob_end_flush();
     header("LOCATION: case1.php");
     exit;
break;

   case 2:
    $ob_file = fopen('case2.txt','w');
    ob_start('ob_file_callback');
    echo $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    ob_end_flush();
    header("LOCATION: case2.php");
        }
    exit
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no break statement in your first case branch dealing with the "1". 
You *do* send a redirection header, but that is just a header sent to the client. it does *not* terminate execution!

Using the feedback from the discussion in the comments, I try to make things a little clearer:

```
<?php

// writes a given string $buffer into a file handle spcified by the global $file
function ob_file_callback($buffer) 
{ 
    global $ob_file;
    fwrite($ob_file,$buffer); 
    return $buffer;
}

// main(): 

// #####
$forks = 1; // testing only !!
//$forks = 2; // testing only !!
// #####

global $ob_file = FALSE;
switch ($forks) {
    case 1:
        $ob_file = fopen('case1.txt','w');    
        ob_start('ob_file_callback');
        echo sprintf('ip = %s',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        ob_end_flush();
        fclose($ob_file);
        header("Location: case1.php");
        break;
    case 2:
        $ob_file = fopen('case2.txt','w');
        ob_start('ob_file_callback');
        echo sprintf('ip = %s',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        ob_end_flush();
        fclose($ob_file);
        header("Location: case2.php");
} // switch

?>
```

I have not tested that code (so there might be some syntax glitch...). I just want to note down a suggestion of how to get this working...

Comment: Well that may have stopped it from writing to case2.txt, and it now seems to be writing to case1.txt, but there are many other more inexplicable issues going on. Also, i don't know what you mean when you say I'm sending the header but not terminating.

Comment: Not terminating means: the script goes on in execution. It does not simply stop because you call the header() function. Why should it?

Comment: Why do you declare that function ob_file_callback() twice? I am surprised that is possible at all. You certainly want to change that and put the function implementation outside the switch statement. Put it at the start of the script.

Comment: OK, I've extracted the function to outside the cases, but it still won't write to case1.txt, and both header relocations fail. Is exit not good enough? Above in the first round of corrections are the changes.

Comment: Exit terminates, yes. but it is not required here, the switch is fine (expect the strange indentation of the "}"). That global variable also is very ugly, but whatever...

Comment: Have a try fixing the headers you sent. Case is important here. The syntax must be: 'Location: case2.php'.

Comment: Sure, exit terminates, but maybe we don't need terminates, seeing as you recommended to terminate the code before it went on to default. Besides, even if that were the issue, in your world it would locate to my relocation and then back to the default HTML. The switch is failing miserably. Case, what case, that's failing miserably. The syntax, what syntax, it shouldn't be in caps? it should be one apostrophe and not two? Nope, no luck, still fails.

Comment: I did not recommend to terminate anything. I suggested to add a 'break;' so that only one of the case branches gets executed, not both. Wether you terminate the script is another matter.

Comment: 'Case' refers to 'lower case' or 'upper case'. "LOCATION" is different from "Location".

Comment: If you use '' or "" does not make a difference here. But you might want to read about their different meaning inside PHP. That is important.

Comment: What do you mean by "back to the default html" ?

Comment: To solve the header issue, in your first post, you claim the reason is I'm not terminating execution. Maybe you were referring to the break? Location being lower case hasn't solved it for me, it still fails. Thanks anyway, I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I did _not_ say the reason is that you are not terminating. Be precise. I said: jsut sending the header does not automatically terminate the script. What I mean is: although you send the header the script is executed to the end. Thus without the 'break;'the second case branch is execute too, not only the first one. You execute both branches.

Comment: See the code block I added to my answer. Maybe that makes things more understandable for you.

Comment: Well your answer contains global $ob_file = FALSE; which has a syntax error, but erasing it, it still won't work. The reason all of these things weren't working I discovered was because php doesn't tolerate echoing before a header location is sent, even though the place I'd learnt about ob_file claimed that the start and end flush of it cancelled out this danger.

Comment: Yo mean you did not react to the 'headers already sent' warning you got all the time? Or, even worse, you have warnings disabled whilst debugging?